# Mongoose operations with virtual

Tags: node.js, mongoose, virtual

I'm trying to work with virtual attributes in mongoose. I have a user schema with birth attribute. When I want to find a user I use a query to return the age virtual attribute and calculate the age.
I want to know If I can use $lt and $gt against age virtual attribute in the query. Is it possible?

```
UserSchema.virtual('age').get(function() {
      var daysFromNow = moment(this.individual[0].birth.year, "YYYY").fromNow();
      var daySplit = daysFromNow.split(" ");
      return daySplit[0];
});
```

Thanks you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

per my understanding Virtuals are NOT available for document queries or field selection. Only non-virtual properties work for queries and field selections.